# Thmtools and \declaretheoremstyle in Beamer

Tags: beamer, environments, amsthm, thmtools

I am trying to define a custom theorem environment using thmtools. It works as expected in e.g., `\documentclass{article}`, but in `beamer` I receive the error

> "use of \ifbeamercolorempty doesn't match its definition"

and compilation ends. Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames},notheorems]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\colorlet{theoremblue}{blue!4}
    \declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=6pt, 
    spacebelow=6pt,
    headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
    bodyfont=\itshape,
    postheadspace=1em,
    qed=\qedsymbol,
    shaded= {rulecolor=blue,
            rulewidth=2pt, 
            bgcolor=theoremblue
            },
]{myplain}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=myplain]{theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{theorem}[test]
Let $x$ be \ldots
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Uhm, interesting. The issue is with `\qedsymbol`. As far as I understand `thmtools` use a `\protected@edef` which works with the standard classes but not with `beamer`.

Comment: Nice observation. Removing the qed= line works, but the output is still quite different between article and beamer classes.

Comment: I've reported this to `thmtools` (which is currently maintained by myself), see https://github.com/muzimuzhi/thmtools/issues/17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To internally redefine the `\qedsymbol` to the value of option `qed` while allowing usage `qed=\qedsymbol`, `thmtools` uses `\protected@edef\qedsymbol{<value of option "qed">}`. This assumes that the `\qedsymbol` can bear `\protected@edef`. But `beamer` redefines `\qedsymbol` to

```tex
\def\qedsymbol{\leavevmode\hbox{\usebeamertemplate*{qed symbol}}}
```

in which `\usebeamertemplate` is fragile hence the whole cannot bear.

In the following example, a protected wrapper of `\qedsymbol`, `\xqedsymbol` is provided, and you can safely use `\xqedsymbol` in the value of key `qed`.

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames},notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\colorlet{theoremblue}{blue!4}

\makeatletter
% a robust wrapper of \qedsymbol
\protected\edef\xqedsymbol{\unexpanded\expandafter{\qedsymbol}}
\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=6pt, 
    spacebelow=6pt,
    headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
    bodyfont=\itshape,
    postheadspace=1em,
    qed=\xqedsymbol,
    shaded= {rulecolor=blue,
            rulewidth=2pt, 
            bgcolor=theoremblue
            },
]{myplain}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=myplain]{theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{theorem}[test]
    Let $x$ be \ldots
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]